# Set maximum sliderInput value based on reactive output value

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have a Shiny app with a slider input and I would like to set the maximum possible value for the slider based on a maximum value in the dataset uploaded by the user. The max distance will change based on the dataset uploaded.

Here is a minimum working example of what I am trying to do. Below I just hardcode the number for the maxdistance, but in my code it is calculated:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("range_one", "Core:", min = 0, max = textOutput("maxdistance"), value = c(0,0))
)

server <- function(input,output) {
   output$maxdistance <- renderText({ 
    maxdistance <- 250
    return(maxdistance)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in max - min : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Which makes sense because I as asking for a text output, so how do I get this output as a numeric value for use in the sliderInput() function?

Comment: Just use `updateSliderInput` to update the slider on the server side.

Comment: Could you please post an example of how to do this properly? I tried something based on the help, but it is causing the app to crash.

Comment: @user29609, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376629/1247080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      actionButton("change", "Change slider max value")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$change, {
    max = sample(50:100, 1)
    updateSliderInput(session, "bins", max=max)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make a working example based on your answer, but my trouble is now trying to access my calculated value from a reactive function within the observe() function. I can hardcode it, for example max=250, or use max = sample(50:100,1), but I can't seem to access my calculated data which is stored in a data frame. I tried: data <- data(), max = max(data$distance), but it gives the error: connection reset by peer and crashes the app.

Comment: Huh, it seems the action button is necessary. If I add it, it does not crash. I think the app was crashing because it relies on uploaded data to get the max value, so we need to keep the defaults until data is uploaded, then click the Change slider max value. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Change as follows, it will work:

```
sliderInput("range_one", "Core:", 
            min = 0, max = as.integer(textOutput("maxdistance")), 
            value = c(0,0))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives the error: Error in findStepSize(min,max,step) (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

Comment: are you using the exact same code with just this line updated? it works for me. You are returning maxdistance (which is an integer initialized to 250) from renderText right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am using on the server side to achieve the desired result of my original question, without the need for an action button:

```
observe({
infile <- input$file # user input file upload
 if(!is.null(infile)) {
  processed <- processed() # list of processed elements returned from earlier reactive({}) function with my app
  processed_data <- processed$processed_data # get the processed data from the list and save as data frame
  maxdistance <- max(processed_data$distance) # calculate the max distance from the processed data
  updateSliderInput(session, "range_one", max=maxdistance) # update the slider called "range_one" based on the maxdistance
  }
```

})

This allows the app to use the default maximum slider value until a file is uploaded. Once the user uploads a file, the data is processed and the slider is updated.