# Disable specific range slider

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a sliderInput with a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 1. Is there a way I can disable the range 0 - 0.2 and 0.8 - 1, so the user can only select from the range 0.2 - 0.8 on the slider?

Note: I don't want to change the maximum and minimum, I want the user to know there is more, but currently not selectable.

I have found valuable information through this [R shiny sliderInput with restricted range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376395/r-shiny-sliderinput-with-restricted-range) post, but I would like to have the same output as whenever I use `shinyjs::disable("")`. Meaning a grey area which can not be obtained.

Thanks!!

Comment: The `ion.rangeSlider` library does not offer this possibility. But you can have a segment showing the available range. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376395/r-shiny-sliderinput-with-restricted-range/56010780#56010780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
sliderInput2 <- function(inputId, label, min, max, value, step=NULL, from_min, from_max){
  x <- sliderInput(inputId, label, min, max, value, step)
  x$children[[2]]$attribs <- c(x$children[[2]]$attribs, 
                               "data-from-min" = from_min, 
                               "data-from-max" = from_max)
  x
}

css <- "
.irs-grid-text {
  color: black;
}
.js-grid-text-0, .js-grid-text-1, .js-grid-text-9, .js-grid-text-10 {
  color: #99a4ac;
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  sliderInput2("slider", "Slide:",
              min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step = 0.1, from_min = 0.2, from_max = 0.8
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: That is one beautiful and easy solution, thank you!