# Shiny updateSliderInput: Convert double-ended to single-ended slider

Tags: r, shiny, slider

I have a double-ended shiny slider input like so:

```
sliderInput(inputId = "years",
                             label="Choose base year and target year",
                             min = 2015,
                             max = 2060,
                             value = c(2015,2060),
                             step = 1,
                             sep = ""
                 )
```

After the user uploads a value, I want to fix the lower end of the slider to a certain value; the upper end should stil be moveable. I tried to achieve this by using the updateSliderInput function, and by just providing one value for the "value" attribute (thus, the slider should become a regular one-ended slider):

```
  observeEvent(upload(), {
    updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "years", min = base_year(), max = 2060, value = 2060)
  })
```

However, this does not work; the slider is still double-ended, and both handles are set to 2060. How can I convert the double-ended slider to a regular one?

Kind regards,

Requin

Comment: Is it a valid option for you to use `renderUI` and 'uiOutput' to archieve that?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56010780/9841389) might also be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution closer to your question, triggering only once after pushing the button:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("Slider_UI"),
  conditionalPanel("input.fixLower == 0", {actionButton("fixLower", "Fix lower range")})
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  fixedLower <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$fixLower, {
    fixedLower(min(isolate({input$years})))
  }, once = TRUE)

  output$Slider_UI <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(fixedLower())){
      sliderInput(inputId = "years",
                  label="Choose base year and target year",
                  min = 2015,
                  max = 2060,
                  value = c(2015, 2060),
                  step = 1,
                  sep = ""
      )
    } else {
      sliderInput(inputId = "years",
                  label="Choose base year and target year",
                  min = fixedLower(),
                  max = 2060,
                  value = fixedLower(),
                  step = 1,
                  sep = ""
      )
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As suggested by @DSGym, here is an example using `renderUI`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId="type_select", label="Select slider type", choices = list("Standard slider", "Range slider")),
  uiOutput("Slider_UI")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Slider_UI <- renderUI({
    req(input$type_select)

    if(input$type_select == "Range slider"){
      presetValues <- c(2015, 2060)
    } else {
      presetValues <- 2060
    }

    sliderInput(inputId = "years",
                label="Choose base year and target year",
                min = 2015,
                max = 2060,
                value = presetValues,
                step = 1,
                sep = ""
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: good solution. OP, if you want to keep the values, think about storing them with `reactiveValues`